# Trouble implementing tabs with AngularJS using stateProvider and ui-view

Tags: angularjs, uiview, angularjs-directive, tabs, angular-ui-router

Hi I have created a simple application that lets you create a new post and see existing posts.

However I am now trying to have tabs with my application. Meaning there is a separate tab for adding a new post, and a separate tab for seeing existing posts. So there should be two tabs. One for adding new post, one for seeing existing ones.

Here is the plunker with how things are supposed to look but isn't working
http://plnkr.co/edit/3HVgE4vq8Z10HBRgzDfv?p=preview

Here is a plunker that works (made by someone else) but doesn't have the following scripts:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dYuXfcMLe7JEg8wVoPkE?p=preview

```
<script type = "text/ng-template" id = "/main.html">
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Post Center</h1>
</div>

<form id = "form" ng-submit="addForm()">
  <h3>New post</h3>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Title"></input>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Name"></input>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>

<h3>Existing posts</h3>

<div ng-repeat="post in posts">

  <span style="color: navy; font-size:15px; text-align: left; display: block;">
    <b>Title</b>:  {{post.Title}}&nbsp&nbsp
    <b>Name</b>:  {{post.Name}}&nbsp&nbsp
  </span>

  <span>
    <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
  </span>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
  </script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
<div class="page-header">
  <h4>
    <br>
    <b>Title</b>:  {{post.Title}}
  </h4>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
  {{comment.author}}

  <span id= "comment">
    {{comment.body}}
  </span>
</div>

<form ng-submit="addComment()">
  <h3> New Comment </h3>
  <div class = "form-group">
    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" ng-model = "body"></input>
  </div>
  <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>
  </script>
```

Please help and get the first plunker to work! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Two changes:

1) Change the `ng-app="Plunker"` in `index.html` to `ng-app="app"` to match your module name.

2) Drop the leading slashes from `templateUrl: '/addPost.html'` to `templateUrl: 'addPost.html'`.

Working Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/cXKFWOzbwX49CHhgARzX?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't actually work because I cannot add posts and see them?

Comment: Have you tried adding corresponding `id` tags to the `ng-templates` ?

Comment: Working version: http://plnkr.co/edit/cXKFWOzbwX49CHhgARzX?p=preview. The final script needs an `id` but I'm not sure exactly what it should be.

Comment: thank you but this isnt working because whenever you add a post, it is not reflected on existing posts page?